# Hadoop OutputCollector Duplicate Keys

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, key

I have some pair  after processing text. K - is a Text and custom V class. K it is a word so it can be duplicated. But after Map function, latest  pair with the same key are replaced the last one. For Example
    (buy,(1,2))    (catch,(2,1)) (buy,(3,3))
In reduce function i receive
    (buy,(3,3)) (buy,(3,3))
and
    (catch,(2,1))

So, how can i collect to the OutputCollector in Map function values with the same keys?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is that

> the iterator in the Hadoop reducer uses a single object whose contents it changes each time it goes to the next value.

Check this [article](https://cornercases.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/hadoop-object-reuse-pitfall-all-my-reducer-values-are-the-same/) for more info.